# What is "early spring" in following sentence?

Tags: prepositions, objects

> The hills here are covered with wildflowers in **early spring**.

At first, I thought it was an adverbial phrase but it's not.
Preposition **in** implies that "early spring" is a noun but how?

Let's look at sentence

> I'll go there **next spring**.

It doesn't need a preposition because "next spring" is an adverbial phrase. How is *next spring* different from *early spring*?

Answer (score 1):

"Early spring" is the "early part of spring", the "beginning of spring", just as "late spring" would refer to the end of spring.

Spring as a season lasts three months, and not all spring flowers flower at the same moment. So a flower that flowers early in spring is said the flower in early spring.

Next spring refers to a time period of three months, early spring to a period of 4-6 weeks.

Comment: Then **early** in mentioned sentence is an adjective, right?

Comment: Yes, it is, it modifies the noun _spring_ :)

Comment: For what it's worth, both "in early spring" and "next spring" are time adjuncts (also known as adverbs of time).

Comment: @DamkerngT. You mean "in early spring" is an adverb as a whole and **in** is not used as preposition?

Comment: It ("in early spring" as a whole) functions as an adverb. (Some people call it an [adverbial phrase](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adverbial_phrase).) *In* is, of course, a preposition.